# Zulu docs for supported JRE flags

Tags: azul-zulu

Where can I find documentation on JAVA_OPTS / JRE flags supported by Zulu

I've looked here but cannot find anything https://docs.azul.com/zulu/zuludocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zulu is a build of the OpenJDK, so the flags on the command line are those for HotSpot, which is the Virtual Machine implementation.

Probably the best place to go for command-line flags is Foojay.io.  For example, the JDK 8 flags are listed here:

https://foojay.io/command-line-arguments/openjdk-8/?tab=alloptions

Other versions can be found under the OpenJDK Command Line Arguments section on the main page.